# Compare meta_query with a Regular Expression and do a less-than operation on it

Tags: post-meta, meta-query, regex

I have the problem that my client is using a theme which stores options of items
in a serialized way in the `post_meta` table.

I already found out that this is not the best way to save values especially if you want to query over them later, but so far I cannot change that fact.

I tried to query it with the `REGEXP` compare option of the `meta_query()` function.

```
$metaquery['meta_query'] = array(
    'key' => '_ait-dir-item',
    'value' => '*\"guestcount\";s:[0-9]+:\"'.$_GET['guestcount'].'\".*',
    'compare' => 'REGEXP'
);
$query->set('meta_query',$metaquery);
```

So I can find the items with the exact geustcount of the user's input.

**But I would like to find all items with `guestcount >= input`.**

How would that be possible?

**UPDATE**

I have tried it now with checking the number for a range with regex (while the regex is beeing created before)

```
$gc = (string)$_GET['guestcount']; //gc...guestcount
$input_regex = $gc[0];

for($i=1;$i<strlen($gc); $i++){
    $input_regex .= "[".$gc[$i]."-9]";
}
$compare_regex = '|[2-9][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]{3}|1[0-9]{4}|20000';
```

the max value of the range is always `20.000`.

**Well ... I dont get any results with this... can anybody see a bug in it?**

This was for the `input = 150`:

`'value' => '*\"guestcount\";s:[0-9]+:\"\b(1|[5-9][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]{3}|1[0-9]{4}|20000)\b\".*`'

**Update**

I cleaned up the regex and removed th `\b` and the `.` and `*` and stuff... now it seems, that I find alle items, where a guestcount is entered ... i.e. `input=300` I also found one with `250 guestcount`...

`'value' => '\"guestcount\";s:[0-9]+:\"(1|[5-9][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]{3}|1[0-9]{4}|20000)\"`'

Comment: heureka. I solved it. The thing was, that the "constant" part, was not that constant. In the `$compare` regex, I also had to use the first `$gc[0]+1` value (exception for `9`). Shell I post it as an answer?

Comment: Great, please add it as an answer ;-) .. and maybe explain how you make sure that the generated regex gives guestcount >= input.

Comment: Agree with @birgire post it as an answer. While I'm at it, I think that your answer is still relevant birgire.

Comment: didnt have time so far ... but i will soon post it